# UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource live updates

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i want to ask what is right way to use this UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource... I need to use this for live updates from api. I get add,remove,change then i have to make sections with items from this data and order the sections and items in sections by some rules...I want to ask if i should do the some logic to update the snapshot every time i get updates from api or i can just create new snapshot and apply it to the datasource. What it will do if i apply new snapshot? Is there some mechanism that compares the snapshot? Or it reloads whole collectionView? Thanks.

Comment: *Is there some mechanism that compares the snapshot?* Yes, it is, that's the main benefit of the diffable data source.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new snapshot after every API update and apply it to the diffable data source.

The diffable data source will compare the hash value of each item identifier in the snapshot to see if the data has changed, and will update the collection view accordingly. If the data remains the same, it will have the same hash value, so no updates will be made to the collectionview.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it can handle also if there is some change inside object or inside another object which is property of parent object? It looks i does not update the ui...it looks it handle just add, remove and move...